# convert apples html from a notes backup file

Tags: iphone, html, webkit, restore

I wanted to restore some of the lost notes that I obtained by using grabbing an iTunes backup (of an iphone 4) and opening up the notes.sqlite file.  When I query the table that contains the notes text:
select zcontent from znotebody
I get the text that is in html format. How can I convert them to a more readable content.  Here is an example of a note:

```
    Meds fir odd<div>Trazadone</div><div>Effexor (&amp; Cd)</div><div>Buspirone</div><div>Clonodine</div><div>Nortriptyline</div><div>Risperdal</div><div>Straterra&nbsp;</div>
```

should be:

```
Meds fir odd
Trazadone
(Effexor & Cd)
Buspirone
Nortriptyline
Risperdal
Straterra<space here>
```

Comment: The html should display that already, do you mean it's missing color/font/etc.? That could be added with a css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats already html. Just paste it into any html file (create a new document in any text editor, paste the code, then save as notes.html on your desktop) and load it in your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I exported all of the messages into a file, added a head and body tag, then displayed in chrome.  That was good enough!